# How do I convert a string field of month and year to a date format in hive (using SAS)?

Tags: date, hive, sas, concatenation, to-date

I am trying to convert two string fields (month and year) into a date field that I can use in Tableau. The table is located in Hadoop. I tried using to_date and concat but the results were that everything came out as null.

```
Proc SQL noerrorstop;
Connect to HADOOP (server=X); 
Execute (set X) by HADOOP; 
Execute (drop Table X) by HADOOP; 
Execute (create Table X as
SELECT month, year
to_date(concat(YEAR,"-",MONTH,"-","01")) as date
from TableX
group by month, year
) by HADOOP;
DISCONNECT FROM HADOOP;
quit;
```

Comment: What character strings do YEAR and MONTH contain?

Comment: specify the format of the date. As a default it is `mmddyyyy`. use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(year,'-',month,'-','01'),'yyyy-MM-dd')) as dt`

Comment: Even `select cast(concat(year,'-',month,'-','01') as DATE) as dt` works perfectly. Year and Month are characters, and resultant column is a `date` column

Answer (score 0):

Missing a comma after year,no need for group by.Also TableX is different from Table X?

```
select month,year,to_date(concat(year,'-',month,'-','01')) as date
from TableY
```

Comment: Hi VK. I added the comma, removed group by and still get the same result (all nulls). Yes, the two tables are different. We can say Table X and Table Y.

Comment: @M.Belhaj What do you get when you query select year,month from Table Y?